# How to filter using a dropdown in a gridview and display all values when none is selected

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a web page with 3 values (1 text box, and 2 drop-downs) and displays result in a gridview. This is working great when the value that I want to search is in the drop-down. However, if the user didn't select one of the dropdownlist ( facilityCode), we would like to display all facility codes versus only one. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?  Below is the code related to the sqldatasource:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HCSCRMConnectionString %>"                     
                SelectCommand="SELECT MMM_Id_Nbr, Item_Desc, Supplier_Nbr, Supplier_Name, Stocking_Facility_Code, Reorder_Point_Qty, BodID, Active_Ind FROM BOD_ROP_TBL WHERE (MMM_Id_Nbr = @MMM_Id_Nbr)and active_Ind=@Active_Ind and Stocking_Facility_Code=@FacilityCode"                                      
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE BOD_ROP_TBL SET Reorder_Point_Qty = @Reorder_Point_Qty, Active_Ind = @Active_Ind WHERE (BodID = @BodID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:FormParameter FormField="txt3MID" Name="MMM_Id_Nbr" Type="String" />
                    <asp:FormParameter FormField="dropActive" Name="Active_Ind" Type="String" />
                    <asp:FormParameter FormField="FacilityCode" Name="FacilityCode" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
```